# Exit code 134 returned from process: file in azure devops on the time of CD pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, nodes

I have setup Cd pipeline on a virtual machine then

I got this error the Exit code 134 returned from the process:

file name

`'C:\azagent\A2\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\azagent\A2\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.184.2\deployiiswebapp.js"`'.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? I've the same error...

Answer (score 1):

try to add node.exe installer file from v14.18.1 and place it under the host-agent to use it
Note that we had use v14.18.1 only which is compatible for windows web app in this case.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).